# UITableViewCell expanding cell but cutting off content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view where I have implemented expanding table cells. It works perfectly on iOS 6 on iPhone. I'm updating the app for iOS 7 for iPad only. The same table, with most of the same code, is having a hit or miss problem where the expanded text is sometimes cut off -it's not always cut off, just sometimes, and I have not found a pattern. As soon as I scroll the view even 1 pixel, the text shows up and the view is correct. So clearly it's some kind of refresh, not a problem with the expanding of the cell itself.

I've tried a few things to refresh the cell or table, but those things interfere with the smooth animation of [beginUpdates/endUpdates].

[image: table view]
<sub>(source: [paveglio.com](http://www.paveglio.com/postimages/cdna-row-cutoff-20140220.png))</sub>

Here's the block of code I'm using for the expanding of the cell:

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    //the toggle button calls this method to toggle row height
    //get the touched/tapped button location and translate it to a row
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.optionsTable];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.optionsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        if ([[[OptionCodeStore sharedStore] optionForIndexPath:indexPath] cellHeight] > baseCellHeight) {
            //the cell is already expanded, so toggle back to small size, use default value
            [[[OptionCodeStore sharedStore] optionForIndexPath:indexPath] setCellHeight:baseCellHeight];
            [[[OptionCodeStore sharedStore] optionForIndexPath:indexPath] setCellExpanded:NO];
            [[(OptionCell *)[self.optionsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] optMoreCmtBtn] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MoreDot.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            //ask the cell at row X to get its expanded size
            float expSize = [(OptionCell *)[self.optionsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] expandedCellHeight];
            //put new size into row heights array
            [[[OptionCodeStore sharedStore] optionForIndexPath:indexPath] setCellHeight:expSize];
            [[[OptionCodeStore sharedStore] optionForIndexPath:indexPath] setCellExpanded:YES];
            [[(OptionCell *)[self.optionsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] optMoreCmtBtn] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LessDot.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    //automagically expand/reload rows
    [optionsTable beginUpdates];
//    [optionsTable reloadData]; //reloads full view but makes animation jerky
//    [optionsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; //still not 100% perfect
    [optionsTable endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method to proper values?

Comment: Yes, it's implemented already.

Comment: [optionsTable reloadData]; will also have the bug? I think it a problem that the return value in -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath not proper